# Better performance for MySQL query getting last or most recent score of the day for each day

Tags: mysql

So, this actually does work as needed, but may have performance issues when used with full test of hundreds of questions for a million tests, etc.

- each test creates one row in "tests" table
- query should group by day of the month
- should only grab most recent test of day, even if only by a minute.

I'm sort of a SQL newbie, so any performance tips or schema suggestions on how to do this better would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Hopefully, this SQL Fiddle link will work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef8ef/1

```
-- Get last test score of the day for each day.

CREATE TABLE tests (
  id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_key CHAR(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
  q1_answer TINYINT(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  q2_answer TINYINT(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  date_taken timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO tests VALUES
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 11, 33, '2016-01-10 16:01:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 3, 55, '2016-01-10 19:01:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 100, 44, '2017-03-03 12:01:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 37, 66, '2017-06-10 15:01:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 96, 77, '2017-06-10 20:12:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 6, 99, '2017-06-10 20:13:01'),
(DEFAULT, '007userkey', 2, 22, '2017-09-12 00:01:01');
```

---

```
-- Works, but all this for each test question?

-- Question #1
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t1.date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
  t1.q1_answer AS q1score
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(date_taken) AS maxval
    FROM tests
    WHERE user_key = '007userkey' 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d')
) AS t2
  INNER JOIN tests AS t1
  ON t1.date_taken = t2.maxval
  ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d') ASC;

-- Question #2
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t1.date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
  t1.q2_answer AS q2score
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(date_taken) AS maxval
    FROM tests
    WHERE user_key = '007userkey' 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d')
) AS t2
  INNER JOIN tests AS t1
  ON t1.date_taken = t2.maxval
  ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date_taken, '%Y-%m-%d') ASC;
```

---

Desired result for this example (as shown in SQL Fiddle) would be to have the most recent or last score of each test for each day, formatted like so:

```
date         q1score
2016-01-10   3
2017-03-03   100
2017-06-10   6
2017-09-12   2

date         q2score
2016-01-10   55
2017-03-03   44
2017-06-10   99
2017-09-12   22
```

FYI... PHP will use this to make JSON-based charts for **each question** similar to this:

```
"q1scores":[{"day_taken":"2017-09-04","score":100},{"day_taken":"2017-09-10","score":100}]
"q2scores":[{"day_taken":"2017-09-04","score":100},{"day_taken":"2017-09-10","score":100}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired result? Incidentally, enumerated columns are often symptomatic of poor design. What if there was a q3?

Comment: Good idea to add desired results inline, done.  There will be a fixed amount of questions per test, so to add a third question, I would add an additional column **q3_answer**... Not sure what the better design would be, since I may need to query everyone's q3 answers at some point, etc. Thanks for your help though. :-)

Comment: A better design would be a separate table. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing!